# How can we align child div right side of the parent div

Tags: html, css, django

In my below code I have one anchor tag and inside that anchor tag I have one div. So here what i am trying is to align both anchor tag and div side by side. In my case while I am giving left and right property to div then it is hiding inside anchor tag it is not appearing left and right so how can we align it side by side like left side is anchor and right side is div.

```
        {% if CategoriesBar%}
        {% for Categories in CategoriesBar %}
        <a class="trigger" href="{% url 'getProductsByCategory' Categories.cat_name {{Categories.cat_name}}
            <div class="sub">
                 {% for subCategories in SubCategoriesBar %}
                                {% if Categories.cat_id == subCategories.parent_id %}

                <div class="item">{{subCategories.cat_name}}</div>
                   {% endif %}
                   {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

**css**

```
.trigger {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bada55;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 120px;

  background: #4863a0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
```

Comment: don't you use bootstrap?

Comment: no i did not used bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change div element's display from block(default) to inline(same as anchor element) so they can be in the same line.